# Laravel validate float number lenght (not value of float)

Tags: php, laravel, validation, double

I want to validate the length of a float number, not the value itself I am talking about the length. The length should be max 9.

Examples:

```
0              OK
0.00           OK
5              OK
20             OK
100            OK
4000           OK
100000         OK   
100000000      OK
100000000,00   OK
1000000000     NO its 10 digits long
```

Please note, if the number contains decimals they should not count!

This is what I have tried so far:

1. `max:9` this always results in validating the value instead of the length of the number
2. `digits_between:0,9` always returns in `The price old must be between 0 and 9 digits.` even tho the value is `12.51` which I don't get
3. `size` will not work for me because it's a fixed length

Any ideas on how to solve this? I don't get why `digits_between:0,9` is not working even though the documentation is saying `length` instead of `value` (Quote: `The field under validation must have a length between the given min and max.`).

I am using Laravel 8.

Kind regards

Comment: It sounds like you want to verify the number is less than 1000000000.

Comment: How about a `regex:/[\d.]{,10}/` sort of rule (not this simple but you get the idea)?

Comment: However, I would like to know why `digits_between` doesn't work although the documentation is talking about `length`: `length between the given min and max`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you are basically looking for this.

```
max:999999999
```

Comment: Sometimes we can't imagine how easy the solution can be before we see it.